# Precompile ASP.NET MVC views when Git-publishing to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We are using simple `git push` to deploy/publish our web site (ASP.NET MVC 5) to Azure websites.

Is there a way to request precompilation of MVC views? I'm hoping there is a setting that would be entered into `app settings` section on the `CONFIGURE` tab in Azure portal, but I wasn't able to find what that could be.